# When starting Docker containers, host machine loses internet connection

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network-programming, docker-network

## Problem:

When I start several Docker containers from a `docker-compose.yml` file, the internet connection on my host machine is not working anymore. As soon as I shut down all Docker containers, the internet connection on my machine is immediately restored. 
This only happens if the number of containers I am starting is above 32.

---

## Procedure:

The service I want to start is specified in a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  agent_1:
  ....
```

I am starting the containers by following command (using 40 as an arbitrary number of containers):

```
docker-compose up --build --scale agent_1=40 agent_1
```

---

## Solution approaches:

I tried the approaches listed below, but so far, none of them worked for me.

#### #1: Specifying a IPv4 subnet for the Docker containers

I created a network by following command:

```
docker network create --driver bridge agent_network --subnet 10.10.1.0/24
```

Hence, I edited the `docker-compose.yml` file to use the custom network:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: agent_network

services:
  agent:
    ...
```

#### #2: Creating a IPv6 Docker network

First, I edited the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file in order to enable IPv6:

```
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "2a01:4f8:a:b::/64",
 }
```

Then, I created a network, analogously as before:

```
docker network create --driver bridge --ipv6 --subnet=2a01:4f8:a:b:c::/80 agent_network
```

As the network has the same name as in approach #1, the `docker-compose.yml` file was the same.

#### #3: Creating a MacVLAN Docker network:

In this approach, I configured the `docker-compose.yml` file to use a Docker network based on the macvlan driver and connecting to my local ethernet adapter (enp34s0)

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  dockervlan:
    name: dockervlan
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp34s0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "10.10.2.0/24"
          gateway: "10.10.2.1"

services:

  agent_1:
    networks:
      - dockervlan
    ...
```

---

## System specifications:

Host machine OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Host machine IP: 192.168.0.34
Docker: 20.10.22
docker-compose: 1.29.2

I also tried to use a remote server running a VM (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS) which however led to the same behaviour.
Further, I made sure there are no conflicts regarding the IP ranges on either system.

##### I would greatly appreciate any ideas or alternative approaches regarding this problem.

Comment: It seems like [you already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889547/cant-use-more-than-32-docker-containers-networking-issues); is this essentially any different from what you asked a week ago?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34760791
(I tried it and it worked for me)

The solution is to create or edit /etc/connman/main.conf with the following:

```
[General]
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist=vmnet,vboxnet,virbr,ifb,docker,veth,eth,wlan
```

And restart connman.

As described [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-no-network-when-running-a-container-in-arch-linux/5494/5).